# Adding data to a newly created axis in an ndarray python

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I just created a new axis to expand my array from 3d to 4d (named X), however, the 4th axis has just 1 element of type None, I want to append a 1d array(s) to the newly added 3rd axes or 4th dimension. I used the np.newaxis function to create the 4th dimension.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(10,5,6)
X = X[:,:,:, np.newaxis]

s = np.random.rand(10)
```

Comment: Can you share input example?

Answer (score 0):

To add another dimension to an array, you can use numpy.append() with an axis of 0. As an example

```
import numpy as np

sample_array = [[1], [2], [3]]
sample_array = np.append(sample_array, [[None]], axis=0)

print(sample_array)
```

Which will return

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [None]]
```

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to add data points to the newly created dimension or axis

Comment: Yes, you can simply assign the value by index as a normal array. Using that same system, do `sample_array[3] = [4]` and that will set the value to the existing item of the 3rd (technically 4th) dimension